# Which interface is better/faster - USB 2.0 or build-in card reader

Tags: windows-7, usb, sd-card, usb-storage

- Which interface is better/faster - USB 2.0 or build-in card reader ?
- What is the upper speed limit for those interfaces - cards can read up to 100MB/s, but I think it will be limited by the interface ?

I have Samsung NP-R780 laptop. I would like to extend the disk space by adding small(physically) external memory (external drive is to big) to store the data. Not to run apps from it. I plan to use regular SDCard.

Thank you for answers

Comment: What interface does the built-in reader use, most are just internal USB devices in my experience

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information about your built-in card reader.  *Your answer cannot be answered correctly without that information.*

Answer (score 1):

> Which interface is better/faster - USB 2.0 or build-in card reader ?

It really depends on your machine (I don't have a NP-R780 around). In my case, the SD card reader is plugged into the USB interface anyway (and I never experienced differently).

To confirm:

- Linux: Check via `lsusb` (something like *Smartcard Reader* may appear)
- Windows: Use the *Device Manager* and check whether your card reader is listed under *Universal Serial Bus controllers*

> What is the upper speed limit for those interfaces - cards can read up to 100MB/s, but I think it will be limited by the interface ?

Yes, but the interfaces are the same in most cases. It really boils down in chosing a proper card / USB stick

Answer (score -1):

Not enough information to answer your question, though it probably won't make much of a difference in practice anyway.

The speed of the card reader would seem to vary with the model you get.  And the speed of the internal card reader's internal interface would depend on what that internal interface is.  My guess is that the bottleneck would tend to be the card or/and the card reader, rather than the interface.

It's probably best to just get the one that's more convenient for you.  If you get an internal one, it's built-in, so you don't need to worry about handling it separately.  But if you get an external one, you might be able to use it with other computers too.

Comment: -1 issued; If there isn't enough information to answer the question, the author should provide additionally information, before an answer is submitted.

Comment: @Ramhound Given that neither I nor the other responder had the necessary information, why was only my response downvoted?

Comment: I would be more then happy to explain the reason I only down voted your answer in Root Access, even though, I actually already have explained my vote.  If you must know, I am still trying to decide if I should vote on the other answer, I have not yet decided.